# gatt.disconnect() is initiated host but not by the app

Tags: bluetooth, wireshark, android-ble

I've been breaking my head with this issue....

i send a gatt.write command to my remote device, sometimes getting response and sometimes not because the gatt disconnects at all times from my app! (when using the nrf app for writing this value it doesnt disconnect)

when exploring the issue with WireShark using btsnoop_hci.log
I see that the host is initiating disconnect, but my app is not sending!!! went over with debugger on every possible disconnect.

I'm attaching the log output:
[image]